# __pairs() and __ipairs() metamethods does not work at all

Tags: lua, meta-method

I don't know what I do wrong. Basically the code looks like this:

```lua
local t = setmetatable({}, {__pairs = function (self)
    print "Message from __pairs()"
    return function ()
        ...
    end
end})
for k, v in pairs(t) do ... end
```

The same for __ipairs(). Overloaded metamethods aren't called at all - no console output, no custom iteration at all. Instead I get the result as if I iterate through a table without metatable. What's wrong?

Comment: Which version of Lua are you running? Try the [online demo](https://www.lua.org/demo.html).

Answer (score 3):

You most likely use Lua 5.1 (or its derivative), which [doesn't have support for these metamethods](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8), as these were introduced in Lua 5.2. I've tested in Lua 5.2-5.4 and confirmed that your code works there (the method is called).

Comment: I use Lua 5.4.2 which is running under Windows 10

Comment: I ran the following code in the online demo that runs 5.4:
`
local t = setmetatable({}, {__pairs = function (self)
    print "Message from __pairs()"
    return function () return nil end
end})
for k, v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end
`

Answer (score 0):

for those who are not working on `__pairs` and `__ipairs` in older versions (for example, Solar2D is running on Lua 5.1), you can override the pairs and ipairs functions to add supports in main.lua using the following code:

```lua
local raw_pairs = pairs
pairs = function(t)
    local metatable = getmetatable(t)
    if metatable and metatable.__pairs then
        return metatable.__pairs(t)
    end
    return raw_pairs(t)
end

local raw_ipairs = ipairs
ipairs = function(t)
    local metatable = getmetatable(t)
    if metatable and metatable.__ipairs then
        return metatable.__ipairs(t)
    end
    return raw_ipairs(t)
end
```